# Activity not declared in Manifest (Apparently)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, timer

I can't for my life figure out why it keeps saying "unable to find Explicit Activity Class com.example.timer.beep. Have you declared the Activity in your Android Manifest?". As far as I can tell it has been declared and i have followed the convention of the last small app I built. My xml files are lowercase, my .java files are CamelCase. Does anyone have any other ideas as to why it would give me this error? The  error is in the readyToBeep function in MainActivity.java.

Main Activity.java

```
package com.example.timer;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void readyToBeep(View v)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Beep.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Beep.java

```
package com.example.timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Beep extends Activity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buzz);
}

private Context Context;
 Timer timer;

 public Beep(){};

    public Beep(Context Context) {

this.Context = Context;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(),
                   0,        //initial delay
                   1*1500);  //subsequent rate
     }

      class RemindTask extends TimerTask {


          public void run() {


            MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Context, R.raw.beep);  
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mPlayer.start();      

        }    

    }

    public void main(String args[]) {

          new Beep();
            }       
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.timer"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.timer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity android:name="com.example.timer.buzz" >
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

TIA

Comment: It very clearly is not in the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unable to find Explicit Activity Class com.example.timer.beep. Have you declared the Activity in your Android Manifest
```

There is no declaration of your `Beep` activity in your manifest. Add it :

```
<activity android:name="com.example.timer.Beep" >
</activity>
```

Comment: dough!! Sleepy, Associated activity with the name of the actual layout.